# Have Google index site with certain get variables?

Tags: google, google-search, google-index

How can I tell Google to index my site using different get variables?

Example:

```
www.example.com
```

`www.example.com?lg=en` (prevent any index from this link, by default my site is in english)

```
www.example.com?lg=sp

www.example.com?lg=fr

www.example.com?lg=jp
```

Comment: Just to clarify this, by variables, I think you mean parameters that indicate the language of the content?

Comment: @dan right, sorry let me fix that

Comment: Sorry if I don't understand, but wouldn't a site map do just fine?

Answer (score 1):

Given that these are translating into different languages and I'm assuming you want Google to surface the French site in French searches (and etc.), you may want to check out the hreflang tag (https://support.google.com/webmasters/answer/189077?hl=en). You would specify the language for each URL as well as the country code. For English, you'd specify the version of the URL with no query string. Something like:

> <link rel="alternate" href="http://www.example.com?lg=sp" hreflang="es-us" />
>
> <link rel="alternate"href="http://www.example.com" hreflang="en-us" />

There is also a cool hreflang generator at:
http://www.aleydasolis.com/en/international-seo-tools/hreflang-tags-generator/